# Select top values per column in R

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr

This might be a basic question but I haven't found an answear that fits my needs even though there are many alike.

I am trying to select the top 3 values from each column (keeping the row number as an id) but I haven't been able to find the right function for it.

I have a matrix like this from the beggining, using that code to add the id column

```
top_probs <- doc_topic_distr %>% 
  magrittr::set_rownames(seq_len(nrow(.))) %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "id") 

    id          V1          V2          V3          V4          V5          V6          V7          V8          V9          V10          V11          V12
1   1       0.000000000 0.000000000 0.133333333 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.181481481 0.685185185
2   2       0.950000000 0.000000000 0.050000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
3   3       0.028571429 0.114285714 0.814285714 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.014285714 0.028571429
4   4       0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.002127660 0.240425532 0.136170213 0.408510638 0.076595745 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.136170213
5   5       0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.025000000 0.025000000 0.050000000 0.900000000
6   6       0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.076923077 0.384615385 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.284615385 0.253846154
7   7       0.000000000 0.000000000 0.347826087 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.243478261 0.000000000 0.026086957 0.000000000 0.143478261 0.239130435
8   8       0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.024000000 0.004000000 0.000000000 0.460000000 0.000000000 0.224000000 0.288000000
9   9       0.000000000 0.000000000 0.311111111 0.000000000 0.011111111 0.000000000 0.011111111 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.388888889 0.277777778
10  10      0.000000000 0.466666667 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.266666667 0.200000000 0.000000000 0.066666667 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
11  11      0.000000000 0.153333333 0.006666667 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.826666667 0.000000000 0.013333333 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
12  12      0.295833333 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.404166667 0.004166667 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.295833333
13  13      0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.009090909 0.790909091 0.154545455 0.009090909 0.009090909 0.000000000 0.027272727 0.000000000
14  14      0.000000000 0.155555556 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.033333333 0.033333333 0.011111111 0.000000000 0.533333333 0.011111111 0.222222222
15  15      0.055555556 0.000000000 0.533333333 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.177777778 0.005555556 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.227777778 0.000000000
16  16      0.000000000 0.153333333 0.006666667 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.826666667 0.000000000 0.013333333 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
17  17      0.295833333 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.404166667 0.004166667 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.295833333
18  18      0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.009090909 0.790909091 0.154545455 0.009090909 0.009090909 0.000000000 0.027272727 0.000000000
19  19      0.000000000 0.155555556 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.033333333 0.033333333 0.011111111 0.000000000 0.533333333 0.011111111 0.222222222
20  20      0.055555556 0.000000000 0.533333333 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.177777778 0.005555556 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.227777778 0.000000000
```

Now, I want to know if there is a way to use `top_frac()` based on every column, meaning like I want 20% of my data gathered by the same number of highest probability rows per columns. Like if the 20% of the whole data was a 120, then I would get a matrix merging the highest 10 probabilities for each column. It would be easy doing it based on a single column, but I don't know how to do it based proportionally on each one of them.

Comment: When you say 20% of your data, do you mean 20% of rows or 20% of cells?

Comment: You can't keep your data in wide format bc the ID that contains the top values will be different per column (technically you could show it as wide with a lot of NAs). Instead you can use tidyr to gather your non-id columns, then use top_n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up from above, it would be something like:

```
df %>%
  gather(column, value, -id) %>%
  group_by(id, column) %>%
  top_n(3)
```

Comment: Served as a great guide, ended up using this `size <- round((nrow(doc_topic_distr)*.2)/ncol(doc_topic_distr),0) # of docs per topic
top_prob_by_topic <- doc_topic_distr %>% 
  magrittr::set_rownames(seq_len(nrow(.))) %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "id") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = "Topic", values_to = "Prob") %>% 
  group_by(Topic) %>% 
  top_n(size, Prob) %>% 
  sample_n(size = size, replace = FALSE) %>%   
  arrange(Topic, Prob)` and merging it with the initial matrix so I didn't lose the other probs.